# Sending GET request using Arduino, ESP8266 to IFTTT

Tags: get, arduino-uno, esp8266, ifttt

So basically, I have created a recipe in IFTTT which make use of the MAKER.
So IF maker, THEN send SMS.
But apparently the GET request can't seem to get through.

This is my GET statement, am I missing out anything?
Button is my event name. KEY is my key from the maker.

```
String url = "/trigger/Button/with/key/?key="KEY"";
esp8266.println("GET "+ url +" HTTP/1.1");
```

Apparently I'm getting bad request and sometimes wrong syntax.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing a `Host` header:

```
GET /url HTTP/1.1
Host: www.targetsite.com
```